# NullPointerError on a view in Android getView in an Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

Here's my getView in a nutshell. I am PURPOSEFULLY not obliging to the view holder pattern which is why I'm flustered as to why this example is not working. I'm working on this example to show why the view holder pattern is useful, as well as getViewTypeCount() and such. Any ideas?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    if (userPic != null) {
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_1, null);
        }

        TextView prime = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.prime);
        prime.setText("test");

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        //NPE happens here
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        return v;
    } else {
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_2, null);
        }

        TextView prime = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.prime);
        prime.setText("test 2");

        Button button = (Button) v
                .findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        //NPE happens here
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return v;

    }
}
```

Look for `//NPE happens here` for the two spots I get a NPE. Even though I shouldn't be getting one at all since View v is always set up. I have two separate xml layouts, but they only differ with one having an ImageView and one having a button. I have tried deleting my gen and cleaning my project.

Answer (score 0):

## Inflate layouts the right way

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_apps, parent,false)
```

Using this form with `false` is important.

Comment: Can you explain why? I thought passing in a null parent was enough?

Comment: Android needs to know who the parentView is. It attaches it automatically. It's auto-attaching to null that's when you get NPE. You need false because if you pass in true, you're trying to reattach the view to its parent again and that'll be another exception

Comment: @user2676468 please click on the check mark to the left of this answer and upvote, if this worked for you.

Comment: Tried out your suggestion. It doesn't work. I still get the NPE.

Comment: @user2676468 Then are you sure there are my_button and my_image in respective layouts, I don't see other reasons why the references should be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your prime textviews and buttons inside the if and else blocks where you did the view inflation.

Answer (score 0):

In place of ...

```
View v;
```

that is used every where in your code use

```
convertView
```

variable that is in the parameter of the getView();

Thanks....